# File.Exists returns true after File.Delete

Tags: c#, file-io

I have the following method to delete a file with a provided path

```
private void DestroyFile(string path)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Delete(path);
        }
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            throw new IOException(string.Format("Failed to delete file: '{0}'.", path));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I am getting the IOException that is thrown if the file exists after the File.Delete method. Specifically

> System.IO.IOException): Failed to delete file: 'C:\Windows\TEMP\[FILE NAME]'.

I have also confirmed that the file does not exist at the location in the path variable after the execution is complete. I am wondering if I am running up against a race condition between the file system updating after File.Delete and checking against it again with File.Exists. Is there a better way to smoothly delete? I know that File.Delete won't return an error if the file doesn't exist so maybe these checks are a bit redundant. Should I check if the file is in use rather than if it exists at all?

Some important additional information:
The program can and does run successfully often but this particular error has been frequently seen recently.

Comment: This statement... `I have also confirmed that the file does not exist at the location in the path variable after the execution is complete.` ...contradicts the possibility of this... `I am wondering if I am running up against a race condition between the file system updating after File.Delete and checking against it again with File.Exists.` I strongly suspect something is creating the file after you made your call to `Delete()`.

Comment: I thought that `C:\Windows` is a locked directory.  An application must be admin to delete.  Also with it being in a Windows directory, it is possible that something is using the file.

Comment: @Greg I looked into permissions and I can rule that out. It might be an important detail that the method does work some of the time

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ To clarify, I'm saying that maybe a cache hasn't fully updated after the File.Delete so the file still exists in some capacity when the File.Exists check comes through. I am using the GetTempFileName() method to create the temp files though no arguments are passed. I wonder if that could lead to a re-use of file names and thus the issue you've brought up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`File.Delete` will *mark* file for deletion. File really will be deleted only when all handles to it are closed (if there are no such handles - it will always be deleted after File.Delete returns). As documented for [DeleteFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363915(v=vs.85).aspx) winapi function (which is used by C# `File.Delete`):

> The DeleteFile function marks a file for deletion on close. Therefore,
>   the file deletion does not occur until the last handle to the file is
>   closed

Usually there are no open handles to files you delete. Or, if there are open handles - they usually don't have "delete" share (this share allows another process to mark file for deletion), so when you try to delete such file - it either gets deleted (no open handles) or access denied or similar exception is thrown (some handles, but without delete share).

However, sometimes some software, such as antivirus or search indexer, might open arbitrary files with "delete" share and hold them for some time. If you try to delete such file - it will go without errors and file really will be deleted when that software closes its handle. However, `File.Exists` will return true for such "pending delete" file.

You can reproduce this issue with this simple program:

```
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        string path = @"G:\tmp\so\tmp.file";
        // create file with delete share and don't close handle
        var file = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Delete);
        DestroyFile(path);
        GC.KeepAlive(file);
    }

    private static void DestroyFile(string path) {
        try {

            if (File.Exists(path)) {
                // no error
                File.Delete(path);
            }
            // but still exists
            if (File.Exists(path)) {
                throw new IOException(string.Format("Failed to delete file: '{0}'.", path));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

You can retry `File.Exists` check forever in the program above - file will exist until you close the handle.

So that's what happens in your case - some program has open handle to this file with `FileShare.Delete`.

You should expect such situation. For example - just remove that `File.Exists` check, since you marked file for deletion and it will be deleted anyway.

Comment: Wow, this is absolute insanity. Thanks for the heads-up. Assuming you're in an `async` method, following your delete with this line will wait until the file is actually deleted before continuing on: `while (File.Exists(path)) await Task.Delay(100);`

Comment: @Grinn thing is there is rarely reason to do that. File will be deleted when last handle is closed so you can just move on. Unless you want to create another file instead of deleted, but in this case just overwrite contents without deletion.

Comment: I agree. In my case I have an app that has multiple threads each flagging the file paths they are processing while they are being processed, then deleting them prior to unflagging the path. On rare occasions, files were being unflagged before physically removed from the drive due to the circumstances you outlined. This resulted in unexpected behavior because other threads would pick up the file in question. So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

while its not documented in the API, `File.Delete` WILL return before the file is completely deleted.

This is why you are running into the case you are having. Delete call will check for all the things that would make the delete fail (existing handle, lock, permission ect) and it will return after the initiation of `Delete` request

So its relatively safe to just put a while loop right after to wait until the file is gone or use a `FileSystemWatcher`  to watch for Deleted event

Answer (score 0):

`File.Delete` and generally most methods from `System.IO` are dependent on filesystem/streams/etc, whom a bit live their own lives, and are not managed resources, hence `File.Delete` can return before file is physically deleted, but after it's marked for deletion.

After `File.Delete` returns, you can be sure file will be deleted, if not this method will throw exception by itself, so second check with `File.Exists` and throwing `IOException` is unnecessary.

If you want custom exception, catch exceptions from `File.Delete`.

And in code attached, remember that `throw ex;` is diffrenent from `throw;` and changes stack trace to current line.